# Firebase database: ChildEventListener is firing multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On application start the **ChildEventListener** is getting fired the amount of child present in the firebase database. For instance, if I have already 3 children present in the database, the listener will get invoke 3 times when I start my application. s I have defined the code for the listener in my service class and I am starting the service from my Splash class.

From **SplashScreen.class**

```
startService(new Intent(this , BackgroundService.class));
```

From **BackgroundService.class**

listenToJob() method, is in onStartCommand() method of Service

```
 private void listenToJob (){


        String collectionName = "rideRequest";
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(collectionName);


        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

             
                Toast.makeText(BackgroundService.this, "Hey, new child is added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                OnChildCreated(snapshot);
            }



            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };

        myRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

    }
```

I don't what cause this behavior. Isn't onChildAdded() method should only be invoked when a new child is added to the database? I have 3 children already present in the database and when I open my app this onChildAdded() method is getting invoke 3 times.

I want this method to fire up only when child is added to the database!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Firebase documentation on [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events), the `onChildAdded`:

> **is triggered once for each existing child** and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.

So what you're seeing is the expected behavior.

If you want to only be informed of new children, you need to have something that defines when a child is "new". For example, if you're using Firebase's built-in `push()` method to generate the child nodes, you can use the keys that generates to only get child nodes that are generated after you start listening with:

```
String key = myRef.push().getKey()
myRef.orderByKey().startAt(key).addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply and thank you for your time. Yes, now I understand how firebase real-time listener works. I have to do tons of stuff to make it work according to my need. Just once thing if you can clarify, So if I have a listener on my splash activity and I have 1000 children in the database with 1000 fields. So every time I open my app, these children will get fetched. Will it not have a tremendous effect on the cost for fetching/downloading 1000x1000 data everytime i open the app?

Comment: To determine the cost, I'd recommend using the calculator at the bottom of the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). To minimize the cost, only load data that you show to the user, and it seems unlikely that they'll look at a million fields each time the app is first loading up.